# Read memory and send it to another app

Tags: android, memory, bitmap

i'm having hard time figuring out how to send an image which is living only in memory of an aplication to another aplication (aka [something like here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5383797/open-an-image-using-uri-in-androids-default-gallery-image-viwer) but instead reading from filesystem read an image from memory).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

thats what are intents for 
You can also create an socket connection between the 2 apps (its more a quick and dirty solution )
anyway here are some intent examples 
http://www.balistupa.com/blog/2009/08/passing-data-or-parameter-to-another-activity-android/

Comment: How about if i wanted to use another application like android built-in image viewer ?

Comment: @LazyBones, Image viewer supports images in files. There is no way, as far as I know, to send in-memory image to built-in image viewer without writing to disk first.

Comment: save image -> send uri -> wait -> delete image ?