# android open file in gallery without MediaScannerConnection

Tags: android, image-gallery

Hello i am using this code ( https://stackoverflow.com/a/6772455/579646 ) to open an image in Gallery, but on **android 2.2 and 2.3** it shows a me Toast saying "searching for new images and albums ..." and then after about 10 seconds of blank screen it finally shows my image. Plus if i change the image but leave the same file name, the gallery cache kicks in(or something like that) and i see the old image when zoomed out and new picture when zoomed it. The only fix is to use random name every time.

If i use this link https://stackoverflow.com/a/5814533/579646 then it opens faster but then i invade the gallery and it adds a folder to it. Is there a way to remove the folder after the user closes the gallery ?

How can i make Gallery open just one Image **without scanning stuff** and **without adding some folder to the gallery by mediascanner** ?

Thanks

Comment: do the hard work and edit the post instead of downvoting, english is not my native language smartass

Answer (score 0):

Your best option is to create your own Activity for displaying an image within your app ([answers to this question should help](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2169649/open-an-image-in-androids-built-in-gallery-app-programmatically)). You then have complete control over the actions it does. Create a simple activity that takes a path to the image and simply opens that path and displays the image in a full-screen `ImageView`.

I say this because there's not much you can do about Gallery updating its cache whenever it opens - once you move to a different activity, your app has no influence. And `ACTION_VIEW` is the correct Intent to be opening an image, but remember that users may not have the standard gallery as the default activityfor it. If they have a different default, the experience might not be so bad.

Comment: aren't those answers for SELECTING images? i don't need to scroll other images, just see one with the zoom and layout rotation thing

Comment: Sorry, should have been more specific. This comment demonstrates displaying a specific image: http://stackoverflow.com/a/6543674/705048

Comment: Unfortunately, your options are to either implement your own image display or use `ACTION_VIEW` and put up with things you don't like about other implementations, so I'm recommending the first option!