# Opening image in a gallery view

Tags: android, imageview, onclicklistener

Here is my onclick listener for in image obtained from the gallery:

```
imageView.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    Intent intent = new Intent();
                    intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
                    intent.setDataAndType(Uri.parse("mImage"), "image/*");
                    startActivity(intent);
                }});
```

How ever when i click on the image it just shows a blank black screen with the gallery's controls visible. What should i do?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Open an image using URI in Android's default gallery image viwer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5383797/open-an-image-using-uri-in-androids-default-gallery-image-viwer)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
                        Intent intent = new Intent();
                         intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
                         Uri imgUri = Uri.parse("file://" + yourfilepath);
                         intent.setDataAndType(imgUri, "image/*");
                         startActivity(intent);
```

Hope this will work for you.

Comment: @Nirmal How am I supposed to find the path?