# How can I create an intent to handle opening a photo?

Tags: android, image, intentfilter

I have my android application manifest file and I made a new activity.  I want this activity to be able to handle images just like the built in image viewer.  So I can tap an image in the browser, and it will ask if i want to use my application, or the default activity to view the image.  What action can I use in the following intent filter:

```
<intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action." />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
    <data android:mimeType="image/*" />
</intent-filter>
```

I assume it would be listed at http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html but I cannot figure out which one is for viewing images.

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5383797/open-an-image-using-uri-in-androids-default-gallery-image-viwer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are looking for `android.intent.action.VIEW`

[Intent.html#ACTION_VIEW](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#ACTION_VIEW)