# Show all images from a folder in Android's gallery

Tags: android, notifications

I am downloading an image and saving it to a folder, and pushing a Notification, I want when user click on Notification, all the image from that folder in which image in saved should open in the android's default gallery view..below is my code snippet.

```
File file = new File(result);
if (file.exists()) {
    galleryAddPic(file);
// push a notification of image downloaded.     
    NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.fromFile(file));
    PendingIntent pIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, intent, 0);

    Notification notification = new Notification.Builder(context).setContentTitle("Download Complete").setContentText("Image downloaded, click to see.").setSmallIcon(R.drawable.arrow).setContentIntent(pIntent).setAutoCancel(true).getNotification();
    notificationManager.notify(0, notification);
}
```

Comment: With `wan't` you mean: `i don't want to` or `i want to`? Seems like `Wan't` is used in old english style, lol.

Comment: @umesh, Please refer this link it will help you.1.Open Gallery Folder By Click On Notification http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21486415/open-gallery-folder-by-click-on-notification 2. Open an image using URI in Android's default gallery image viwer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5383797/open-an-image-using-uri-in-androids-default-gallery-image-viwer