# Open Gallery Folder By Click On Notification

Tags: android, android-intent, android-notifications, android-gallery

I used this code to send notification.

```
  public static void sendNotificationPhoto(Context context, Class<?> activityTarget)
        {
            Log.i( TAG , "Send Photo Notification");

            NotificationManager mNotificationManager = (NotificationManager) context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
            Notification notifyDetails = new Notification(R.drawable.ic_plusone_standard_off_client, "New Alert!", System.currentTimeMillis());
            Intent intent = new Intent(context, activityTarget);

            int id = NOTIFICATION_ID_PHOTO;
            String contentText = "Slave Picture Is Now Available!";


            PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context.getApplicationContext(), id, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);
            notifyDetails.setLatestEventInfo(context.getApplicationContext(), context.getString(R.string.app_name), contentText, contentIntent);
            mNotificationManager.notify(id, notifyDetails);
        }
```

But now i don't need to open another activity but a specific Gallery's folder. Is it possibile with notification?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this by

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW,ImageUri);
ImageUri = "content://media/external/images/media/1210"`
```

Call this intent in `pendingIntent`

```
PendingIntent contentIntent = 
     PendingIntent.getActivity(context.getApplicationContext(),
                               id,
                               intent,
                               PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT
     );
```

The above Imageuri is for representation.  This worked for me after
several tries with other options. This intent doesnot work if you supply
`file.getpath` or `file.getabsolutepath`

I've tried using `Uri.fromFile` and it worked:

```
intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW,Uri.fromFile(fileName));
```