# Android SAF - How to open directory / folder to a "content://" Uri?

Tags: android, kotlin, storage-access-framework

I have a `Uri`, that looks like this:

```kotlin
// directoryBase value is:
// content://com.android.externalstorage.documents/tree/home%3Amyfolder`
val directoryBase = ...
```

I got it using this code:

```kotlin
            rememberLauncherForActivityResult(
                contract = ActivityResultContracts.OpenDocumentTree(),
                onResult = { uri ->
                    if (uri != null) {
                        viewModel.setDirectory(uri)
                    }
                },
            )
```

I can convert this `Uri` into a document reference (this form is required for `DocumentsContract.createDocument`), using this code:

```kotlin
val id = DocumentsContract.getTreeDocumentId(directoryBase)
// directory is:
// content://com.android.externalstorage.documents/tree/home%3Amyfolder/document/home%3Amyfolder
val directory = DocumentsContract.buildDocumentUriUsingTree(directoryBase, id)
```

The way I am constructing the `Intent` for opening the directory is by using this code:

```kotlin
        Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW)
                .apply {
                    // neither `directory` nor `directoryBase` works, see explanation below
                    setDataAndType(directory, "application/*")
                    flags = Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION
                }
                .run {
                    PendingIntent.getActivity(
                        context.applicationContext,
                        0,
                        this,
                        PendingIntent.FLAG_IMMUTABLE,
                    )
                }
```

What happens?

App selector opens up. `Samsung File` just opens up in the root directory, `Google Files` crashes. To sum up, I expect the folder to open up, but different file managers fail to do it in different ways.

---

Please let me also explain why I don't think is a duplicate question:

- [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41611757/how-to-simply-open-directory-folder?noredirect=1&lq=1) uses `file://` uri
- same goes for [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17165972/android-how-to-open-a-specific-folder-via-intent-and-show-its-content-in-a-file), not to mention that the accepted answer requires `ES file explorer`
- [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21486415/open-gallery-folder-by-click-on-notification) and its [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23496938/4420543) is the same, but it seems that their `content:` uri is different and it does not work anymore with Storage Access Framework

Comment: "I expect the folder to open up" -- I do not know why you would expect that. There has never been a standard protocol for what you are trying to do.

Comment: So there is no way to open the folder that the user selected earlier?

Comment: If by "open" you mean "view the contents", then no, there is no way to open the folder that the user selected earlier, unless you create your own UI for that.

Comment: I don't understand the reason why I can't (why can't Android reverse the `content://com.android.externalstorage.documents` into file access or something), but I take your word for it. Thanks!

Comment: "I don't understand the reason why I can't" -- because Android does not offer the UI that you appear to be seeking. Android does not offer a standard UI for "browse the filesystem". It *does* offer targeted UI for specific actions, such as selecting a document tree (`ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT_TREE`, which you are using via `OpenDocumentTree`). And, it does offer standard UI for "view a document" (`ACTION_VIEW`).

Comment: Have a look at INITIAL_URI. But of course not for ACTION_VIEW.