# Why no image shows?

Tags: android

I have the following Intent to View an image:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW,uri);
intent.setDataAndType(uri,"image/*");
try {
startActivity(intent);
} catch (Exception ex) {
Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),ex.getMessage(),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
```

where the URI is `content://com.android.providers.media.documents/document/image:30506`

but I get "Media non found".

What an i doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5383797/open-an-image-using-uri-in-androids-default-gallery-image-viwer) thread regarding opening image via intent or you can take a look over [here](http://indyvision.net/2010/03/android-using-intents-open-files/)