# How to open External Image (from web) in Android in-built gallery

Tags: android, image

I want to open an image from the web inside in-built android gallery image viewer. So I searched. Found this link
[StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5383797/open-an-image-using-uri-in-androids-default-gallery-image-viwer)

First answer didn't work for me. Following one did.

```
startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("http://www.example.com/example.jpg")));
```

**BUT** It opened the image into browser. I want it to open this with in-built image viewer of android.

Rest of the things that I found work with the local image, not from web.

Basically the idea is to use a method that will open the image in native app, and I'll call that method with Cordova/Phonegap.

Is there any simple way to do it? How can I open the image with url in the native in-built android gallery app??

Comment: is web page is local or from internet?

Comment: @BirajZalavadia Which webpage? Application is built with Cordova. So pages are local. Images are from web that I want to open with android native app.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
 public void openImage(String image) {
  Uri uri = MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI.buildUpon().appendPath(image).build();
  Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, uri);
  startActivity(intent);
}
```

Pass your image path to this method and see if it works.

Hope this has helped!

Comment: Giving me an error. `E/AndroidRuntime(7358): FATAL EXCEPTION: WebViewCoreThread
04-01 11:55:48.297: E/AndroidRuntime(7358): android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: No Activity found to handle Intent { act=android.intent.action.VIEW dat=content://media/external/images/media/http%3A%2F%2Ftest1.latechnologies.net%2Fbanglaporjotonimg%2Fpotenga2.jpg }
04-01 11:55:48.297: E/AndroidRuntime(7358):  at android.app.Instrumentation.checkStartActivityResult(Instrumentation.java:1409)
04-01 11:55:48: E/AndroidRuntime(7358):  at android.app.Instrumentation.execStartActivity(Instrumentation.java:1379)
`