# How to open Image directly with crop option

Tags: android, resize-crop

I want to crop an image , I am able to implement this.

My code is as

```
Intent cropIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK,
                android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);         
        cropIntent.setDataAndType(fileUri, "image/*");
        // set crop properties
        cropIntent.putExtra("crop", "true");    
        cropIntent.putExtra("return-data", true);       
        startActivityForResult(cropIntent, CROP_PIC);
```

where `fileUri` contains URI for path of image which I want to crop from Gallery.

Using this code an alert opens to choose application to select image, I am wondering while I have passed Image path already then why its asking to select application to open Image and when I select application(via Gallery) then I have to choose image from Gallery to crop.

I want a solution using which my image just opens up with crop option without asking to select application to open with ?

Is it possible? please help me to achieve it...

Comment: There's almost no chance unless you are using the content viewer instead. Checkout [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5383797/open-an-image-using-uri-in-androids-default-gallery-image-viwer).

Comment: @androidcode did you find the solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try With This:

```
     String filename = "image.png";
     String path = "/mnt/sdcard/" + filename;
     File f = new File(path);  //  
     Uri imgUri= Uri.fromFile(f);  
     Intent intent = new Intent("com.android.camera.action.CROP");  
            intent.setDataAndType(imgUri, "image/*");  
            intent.putExtra("crop", "true");  
            intent.putExtra("aspectX", 1);  
            intent.putExtra("aspectY", 1);  
            intent.putExtra("outputX", 50);  
            intent.putExtra("outputY", 50);  
            intent.putExtra("return-data", true);
            startActivityForResult(intent, 1);
```

Answer (score 0):

Using the native crop is not good solution, because the behavior of each crop is different. I came across some errors as it is not possible to save a file, is not correct aspect ratio, maybe there are also other.
I think the best solution to use custom crop library after pick photo from gallery. 
There are some good libraries with examples like https://github.com/jdamcd/android-crop or https://github.com/lvillani/android-cropimage or https://github.com/edmodo/cropper