# opening the image with the external gallery using delphi

Tags: android, delphi, firemonkey, delphi-10-seattle

I have created Android app using Delphi 10 Seattle. I have stored the image path and from there I need to open the image in the native Android Gallery. How can I implement this functionality?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Java equivalent of what you're trying to do, looks like this (based on [open-an-image-using-uri-in-androids-default-gallery-image-viwer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5383797))

```
Intent intent = new Intent();
intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
intent.setDataAndType(Uri.parse("file://" + "/sdcard/test.jpg"), "image/*");
startActivity(intent);
```

So if we translate that to Delphi using [sending-android-intents-from-delphi-part-2](http://www.danieleteti.it/sending-android-intents-from-delphi-part-2/) as a guide, we should get code that looks something like this:

```
var
  Data: Jnet_Uri;
  Intent: JIntent;
begin
  Intent := TJIntent.Create;
  Intent.setAction(TJIntent.JavaClass.ACTION_VIEW);
  Data := TJnet_Uri.JavaClass.parse(StringToJString('file://' + '/sdcard/test.jpg'));
  Intent.setDataAndType(Data, StringToJString('image/*'));
  SharedActivity.startActivity(Intent);
end;
```

Of course it's preferable to use

`System.IOUtils.TPath.Combine(Path, Filename)` in place of the '/sdcard/test.jpg'
part of the example code above.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Works perfectly.

Comment: Also, instead of **image**  i have added **audio** and then I can able to play audio in the external player.

Comment: Hi , does anybody know how to do this for IOS?