# Delphi Use android fileprovider to send intent to open and image file with the default android gallery

Tags: android, delphi, android-intent, android-fileprovider

I have tried the solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34558016/opening-the-image-with-the-external-gallery-using-delphi).

I used the solution but It gives FileUriExposedException on my galaxy s9 Plus.

From what I can tell I need to use androids file provider.
Does anyone have an example in Delphi to send an intent to open an image in the default android gallery app, using file provided?

Comment: Refer this: If your targetSdkVersion >= 24, then we have to use FileProvider class to give access to the particular file or folder to make them accessible for other apps. We create our own class inheriting FileProvider in order to make sure our FileProvider doesn't conflict with FileProviders declared in imported dependencies as described here.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38200282/android-os-fileuriexposedexception-file-storage-emulated-0-test-txt-exposed/#38858040

Comment: Which version of Delphi are you using?

Comment: Delphi community  10.3 rio

Comment: I have looked through C:\Program Files (x86)\Embarcadero\Studio\20.0\source\rtl\android and found `JFileProvider` defined in `Androidapi.JNI.Support.pas`. Of course, this means you will have to use a Java answer as a guide to coding the solution in Delphi. That is not a trivial exercise.

Comment: I now have the answer to this question, but I don't have the reputation to request that it be opened again. What should I do?

Comment: I am still trying to figure it out.  The xml solution is not working

Comment: @nolaspeaker  Is it possable  for me to ask you to post your andswer  here in the comments

Comment: I already answered the question in a following question here (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54535225)