# How to scroll among images viewed via intent in android

Tags: android, image, android-intent, scroll, photo

I have created a function to view images in a single view using following Intent.

```
Intent intent = new Intent();
                        intent.setAction(android.content.Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
                        intent.setDataAndType(Uri.fromFile(new File(temp.getPath())), "image/*");
                        startActivity(intent);
```

It opens a default gallery app to view the images. However I cannot go to next image by sliding the screen as it normally happens in simple gallery app. How could I do it? 
The scenario is I have a grid view displaying thumbnails of pics. Now when somebody click on it, it is opened via intent and displayed in full screen but to see next image, user has to go back and then click the next image. What would be the procedure to switch images when a person slide the screen horizontally.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got the answer. Actually, I was not able to swipe the images to see next one because the default gallery app doesn't knew that more image exists in that path. So I notified the media resolver using broadcast intent and then I was able to swipe images.

Comment: Can you please elaborate more (probably explain with code if possible) how did you achieve this. I need to achieve exactly same. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is the swipe event even triggered on the ACTION_VIEW intent?

Comment: The intent provided opens the image in default gallery of the mobile phone. For the default gallery to know that other images also exists in the path and hence swipe to them, we must inform the Media resolver in android of their existence. Broadcast intent are used to notify that an image is available at a particular locaiton.

Comment: @waterbyte Can you provide a link from documentation that achieves this or a similar action?

Answer (score 0):

Intent from application not specify that other images also exist. For gallery to know that other images also exists in the path and hence swipe to them, we must inform the Media resolver in android of their existence. Broadcast intent are used to notify that an image is available at a particular locaiton

Comment: While the answer is correct, but is exactly same as what the accepted answer said. Here's the [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34977224/14291243)