# Android open image in gallery with slide through images

Tags: android, android-intent, android-gallery

I am developing Android camera app, and would like to have feature that is in most of camera apps:

Clicking on the preview icon opens the gallery, that shows current photo and allows to swipe through all images in the camera folder.

When I use Intent.ACTION_VIEW, the gallery shows only 1 image, without possibility to look through other photos in the directory.

Are there any extra flags for intent Intent.ACTION_VIEW to get such behavior?

Is there any workaround to get such behavior?

Comment: Did you find solution to this? I found [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/34977224/1911652) but it's very brief. In case you've found out how to do it please post your answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Are there any extra flags for intent Intent.ACTION_VIEW to get such behavior?

No.

There is no requirement that an Android device have an app that is capable of "shows current photo and allows to swipe through all images in the camera folder". For those devices that happen to have such an app, there is no standard `Intent` structure that demands that the app "shows current photo and allows to swipe through all images in the camera folder".

> Is there any workaround to get such behavior?

Write your own UI for this.

Comment: ... write your own UI as suggested by @Ridcully or install an app that supports swipe i.e. [APhotoManager](https://github.com/k3b/APhotoManager/) where i am the author of and wich is also based on https://github.com/chrisbanes/PhotoView

Comment: OP has specifically menioned **gallery** and yes many apps (e.g. WhatsApp) show image using *gallery* (probably using Intent.ACTION_VIEW) and also allows user to scroll through other images in the same folder.

Comment: @Atul: "OP has specifically menioned gallery" -- there is no requirement for an Android device to contain a gallery app that "shows current photo and allows to swipe through all images in the camera folder". And, even for those devices that have a gallery app, and one that offers such a feature, there is no assurance that `ACTION_VIEW` would trigger that feature.

Answer (score 1):

@CommonsWare might sound a bit harsh, but if you're going to make an App, don't expect you'd need just some magic Intent calls that do all the work for you.

For the kind of thing you want to achieve, look at ViewPager that gives you something to swipe between different views (each of which would then show one image). Chris Bane has provided a nice custom view that allows to view, zoom and scroll pictures: https://github.com/chrisbanes/PhotoView

Comment: Yes, looks like I have to implement custom preview, using PhotoView it seems to be very fast. I just hope that there is some way that allows to show photos in the gallery, that prefers user, instead providing custom interface for common functionality.

Answer (score 1):

[OpenCamera AlmalenceGUI.openExternalGallery()](https://github.com/almalence/OpenCamera/blob/master/src/com/almalence/opencam/ui/AlmalenceGUI.java) uses undocumented action="com.android.camera.action.REVIEW" which in my android-4.2.2 opens the gallery in swipe mode.

```
private void openExternalGallery(Uri uri)
{
    try
    {
        Intent intent = new Intent("com.android.camera.action.REVIEW", uri);
        intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_HISTORY);
        ApplicationScreen.instance.startActivity(intent);
    } catch (ActivityNotFoundException ex)
    {
        try
        {
            Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, uri);
            intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_HISTORY);
            ApplicationScreen.instance.startActivity(intent);
        } catch (ActivityNotFoundException e)
        {
            Log.e("AlmalenceGUI", "review image fail. uri=" + uri, e);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: It is not undocumented (or at least not anymore) but mentioned on [Anroid Developers](https://developer.android.com/about/versions/11/reference/common-intents-30?hl=en-en)