# Path of Image to be passed in Uri.parse to open an image using intent

Tags: android, android-intent

I'm trying to open an image using intent.
The path of the image in my storage is */storage/emulated/0/nitp/download/logo.png*.

My code is

```
Intent intent = new Intent();
intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_DEFAULT);
intent.setDataandType(Uri.parse("/storage/emulated/0/nitp/download/logo.png"),"image/*");
startActivity(intent);
```

I also tried putting *file://storage/emulated/0/nitp/download/logo.png*
and *content://storage/emulated/0/nitp/download/logo.png*

What is the path I should use?

**Solved**
Have to use *file:///storage/emulated/0/nitp/downloads/logo.png*

Comment: It promt the "choose application"  dialogue but the app I select to doesn't open. It closes immediately and I'm again in my app's activity

Comment: what do you see on the logcat after calling `startActivity`?

Comment: also what is the output of `adb shell ls -l /storage/emulated/0/nitp/download/logo.png` ?

Comment: When I try add shell ls storage/emulated/0/nitp/downloads it says no such directory. But instead it shows that directory is /storage/sdcard0/nitp/downloads.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Open an image using URI in Android's default gallery image viwer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5383797/open-an-image-using-uri-in-androids-default-gallery-image-viwer)

Comment: @jannkigandhiya we have to use file:/// instead of file:// ty

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For Pick image from media Storage or SD Card:

```
Intent intent = new Intent();
intent.setType("image/*");
intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Select Picture"), PICK_IMAGE_REQUEST);
```

And For get the path of Image and set in ImageView:

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
            super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
if (requestCode == PICK_IMAGE_REQUEST && resultCode == RESULT_OK && data != null && data.getData() != null) {
        Uri filePath = data.getData();
        try {
            //Getting the Bitmap from Gallery
            imgpath= MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(getContentResolver(), filePath);
            //Setting the Bitmap to ImageView
            imageViewProfileImage.setImageBitmap(imgpath);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Hope this work.