# How to get image from gallery in a .jpg file format?

Tags: java, android, file, bitmapimage

I am trying to get image from gallery. It is giving me image as bitmap. I want the image in .jpg file so that I can save file name in my database.

I have followed this tutorial :

http://www.theappguruz.com/blog/android-take-photo-camera-gallery-code-sample

gallery image selected code:

```
@SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
private void onSelectFromGalleryResult(Intent data) {

    Bitmap bm=null;
    if (data != null) {
        try {
            bm = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(getApplicationContext().getContentResolver(), data.getData());
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    Uri selectedImage = data.getData();

    String[] filePath = {MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA};

    Cursor c = getContentResolver().query(selectedImage, filePath, null, null, null);


    c.moveToFirst();

    int columnIndex = c.getColumnIndex(filePath[0]);

    String picturePath = c.getString(columnIndex);

    c.close();
    File file = new File(picturePath);// error line

    mProfileImage = file;

    profile_image.setImageBitmap(bm);
}
```

I tried this. But I am getting null pointer on file.

Exception :

```
    Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'char[] java.lang.String.toCharArray()' on a null object reference
```

Also I don't want this newly created file to be saved in external storage. This should be a temporary file. How can I do this?

Thank you..

Comment: please check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5383797/open-an-image-using-uri-in-androids-default-gallery-image-viwer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The good news is you're a lot closer to done than you think!

```
Bitmap bm=null;
if (data != null) {
    try {
        bm = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(getApplicationContext().getContentResolver(), data.getData());
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

At this point, if `bm != null`, you have a Bitmap object. Bitmap is Android's generic image object that's ready to go. It's actually probably in .jpg format already, so you just have to write it to a file. you want to write it to a temporary file, so I'd do something like this:

```
File outputDir = context.getCacheDir(); // Activity context
File outputFile = File.createTempFile("prefix", "extension", outputDir); // follow the API for createTempFile
```

Regardless, at this point it's pretty easy to write a `Bitmap` to a file.

```
ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
bm.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, stream); //replace 100 with desired quality percentage.
byte[] byteArray = stream.toByteArray();
```

Now you have a byte array. I'll leave writing that to a file to you.

If you want the temporary file to go away, see here for more info: https://developer.android.com/reference/java/io/File.html#deleteOnExit()

```
Bitmap bm=null;
if (data != null) {
    try {
        bm = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(getApplicationContext().getContentResolver(), data.getData());
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
if (bm != null) { // sanity check
    File outputDir = context.getCacheDir(); // Activity context
    File outputFile = File.createTempFile("image", "jpg", outputDir); // follow the API for createTempFile

    FileOutputStream stream = new FileOutputStream (outputFile, false); // Add false here so we don't append an image to another image. That would be weird.
    // This line actually writes a bitmap to the stream. If you use a ByteArrayOutputStream, you end up with a byte array. If you use a FileOutputStream, you end up with a file.
    bm.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, stream); 
    stream.close(); // cleanup
}
```

I hope that helps!

Comment: I tried your answer that creates a temporary file.. But further I am getting error while converting the file. Can you please check edited question. ? @Eric

Comment: @Sid sorry, I think you misunderstood me. Once you get the bitmap, you want to convert it to a byte array: 'ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
bm.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, stream); //replace 100 with desired quality percentage.
byte[] byteArray = stream.toByteArray();' Once you've converted to a byte array, you then write that array to the file. In your code, it doesn't look like you're doing that.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like your `picturePath` is null. That is why you cannot convert the image. Try adding this code fragment to get the path of the selected image:

```
private String getRealPathFromURI(Uri uri) {
    String[] projection = { MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA };
    @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
    Cursor cursor = managedQuery(uri, projection, null, null, null);
    int column_index = cursor
        .getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA);
    cursor.moveToFirst();
    return cursor.getString(column_index);
}
```

After that, you need to modify your `onSelectFromGalleryResult`. Remove/disable line `String[] filePath = {MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA};` and so on and replace with below.

```
 Uri selectedImageUri = Uri.parse(selectedImage);
 String photoPath = getRealPathFromURI(selectedImageUri);
 mProfileImage = new File(photoPath); 

 //check if you get something like this  - file:///mnt/sdcard/yourselectedimage.png
 Log.i("FilePath", mProfileImage.getAbsolutePath)
 if(mProfileImage.isExist()){
     //Check if the file is exist. 
     //Do something here (display the image using imageView/ convert the image into string)
 }
```

Question: What is the reason you need to convert it in .jpg format? Can it be .gif, .png etc?