# how to view images stored in application directory in gallery

Tags: android

I am building a chat application using socket.io. I want the images sent by the user to be viewed in the gallery.

I am currently using following code to save the image in application directory.
how can I view images stored in "/data/data/com.example.diksha.chatapplication/" directory in gallery?

Code for saving the image

```java
private Uri saveImage(Bitmap image){
        File directory = getContext().getFilesDir();
        String id = UUID.randomUUID().toString();
        File path = new File(directory, id + ".jpg");
        Log.d(TAG, "saveImage: " + path);
        try {
            FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(path);
            image.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, out);
            out.close();
        }catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return FileProvider.getUriForFile(getContext(),getContext().getPackageName() + ".fileprovider", path);
    }
```

Comment: first You need to save to path of saved image in some persistent database . Then to view Use a answer from [This discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5383797/open-an-image-using-uri-in-androids-default-gallery-image-viewer).

Comment: `I am currently using following code to save the image in application directory. how can I view images stored in "/data/data/com.example.diksha.chatapplication/" directory in gallery?` You are saving them to your apps private directory. To `getFilesDir()`. The MediaStore and hence the Gallery app have no access. If instead you would save them to `getExternalStorageDirectory()` or `getExternalFilesDir()` you were done. Nothing else to do then. The MediaStore would find them after a while.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are 2 approaches:

1. First Approach:

Use below code to store your image into Gallery:

```
MediaStore.Images.Media.insertImage(getContentResolver(), yourBitmap, yourTitle , yourDescription);
```

Later, you can see it when you open your Gallery.

2. Second Approach:

Force Gallery to open your folder:

```
Intent i=new Intent();
i.setAction(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
i.setDataAndType(Uri.fromFile(directory), "image/*");  
startActivity(i);
```