# Open an Image in Internal Storage Using Content Provider

Tags: android, android-intent, kotlin, android-contentprovider, android-image

Let's say I package an image with my app and I want to open it with the default image viewer/whatever image viewer the user has chosen to be the default. How would I do that?

There's already this post: [Open an image using URI in Android's default gallery image viewer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5383797/open-an-image-using-uri-in-androids-default-gallery-image-viewer) but many of the answers are obsolete because due to the introduction of android N, a content provider must be used.

The only answer I can find is this one:

```
File file = ...;
final Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW)//
                                    .setDataAndType(VERSION.SDK_INT >= VERSION_CODES.N ?
                                                    android.support.v4.content.FileProvider.getUriForFile(this,getPackageName() + ".provider", file) : Uri.fromFile(file),
                            "image/*").addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);
```

but, according to the author of this solution, this code only works for images stored externally, not ones that may be packaged with my app.

Answer (score 0):

You won't be able to open an image packaged with the app (in drawable or whatever resources) through an external application. You should first copy it into (at least) an [internal file storage](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage#filesInternal). After that you can implement a [FileProvider](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/content/FileProvider) to provide access to this file.

Let me know if you need more details on this. Hope it helped.