# Android doesn't find Intent for opening a PNG File

Tags: android, android-intent, kotlin, intentfilter

So i try to open a PNG File on the system using the Gallery, but for some reason I always get an `ActivityNotFoundException` saying the following :

```
No Activity found to handle Intent { act=android.intent.action.VIEW dat=context://storage/emulated/0/Android/data/com.myapp/files/MyApp/1533800534172image001.png typ=image/* }
```

My code looks like this :

```
val intent = Intent()
intent.action = Intent.ACTION_VIEW
intent.setDataAndType(uri,"image/*")
context.startActivity(intent)
```

Comment: Could you write the content of uri?

Comment: Can you make val intent = new Intent(); and see if it works ?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/40337627/8648705

Comment: @chiappins yes - if i do a file.length() its equal to the size of the file.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is on your variable uri.
it should be like:

```
uri = Uri.parse("file://" + "/sdcard/path-to-your-file.png")
```

Comment: i have tried replacing "context://" with "file://" which leads to a android.os.FileUriExposedException

Comment: yes here can find the right way to avoid this exception: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38200282/android-os-fileuriexposedexception-file-storage-emulated-0-test-txt-exposed